# Changing display name for ArcGIS Experience Builder tabs

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-experience-builder

I'm looking to change the default display name on ArcGIS Experience Builder tabs. I am able to name the tab when I create it, but the name changes to a random number when I add additional widgets to the page. The attached photo shows two rows of tabs. The top row should read "2010" "2015" "2020" and "2021."   The second row should read things like "Population" "Households" and "Median Age." Any tips on how to rename these tabs after adding the desired widgets to the page?

[image: screenshot of Experience Builder tabs titled with random numbers]

Comment: Are these "tabs" a view controller element?